# How can we get licensed songs list through any api(free + paid)? so that we can show list in our app and add it as background music in any videos

Tags: ios, flutter, instagram-api, background-music, instagram-reels

We are implementing a feature in our app to adding a music into the background of video similar to YouTube, Instagram, snapchat.
My question here is- **How can we get the list of licensed audio songs using any api** (**free or paid**) or **any other way** so that we can list that into our app and when **user select song we can add that into background**.

I checked Instagram use their own Audio library.
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHhfx.png)

Similar snapchat I think.
Can anyone here help how can we achieve above challenge?
Thanks in Advance